# Convert a Windows Mobile 6.5 application to Android app with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, cross-platform, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 application that a customer are interested to have the same application for Android devices. I have thought with Xamarin to migrate the application to Android platform. Is it possible or exists some other way/tool to achieve that?

I have read in this [forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14475/windows-ce-and-windows-mobile-6-5-support) that seems it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to directly migrate your app.  Using Xamarin you may be able to reuse existing backend (services, data, models, etc) code, but you will need to rewrite the UI to target the new platform.